# Mutual Exclusion by disabling interrupt

Tags: operating-systems

I am reading *William Stallings* operating system book which gives this pseudo-Code for disabling interrupt to achieve Mutual Exclusion

```
while (true) {
 /* disable interrupts */;
 /* critical section */;
 /* enable interrupts */;
 /* remainder */;
}
```

But I don't get why there is a `While` loop in the code which is `true` 
this means that this part of the code repeats forever but why?

Answer (score 1):

The while loop with true condition is just to ensure this process can enter and exit its critical section repeatedly. This usage is quite common when we are discussing concurrency programming.

Take a moment to reflect. How can you **create an environment to demonstrate easily the effect of two or more different concurrent processes are, for example, contending for one shared resources**? If you let each process just try to enter the critical section once, it might be hard to produce the various particular situations that could happen only to concurrent running processes. It may just happen all processes enter the critical section in order once and then exit.  However, if we use a while(true) loop to run the processes long enough, it will be much more probable to observe all sorts of phenomenons.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: This pattern of using while(true) is very common. You may just check a few more similar examples down that book. For example, the figure 5.6 "Mutual  Exclusion Using Semaphores" of seventh edition. Or figure 5.9. Or figure 5.10.  And several more.